# Youtube API - channels not returning JSON data?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

My javascript is poor to appaling so bear with me.

Got an API call to get the channel data for a specified user. Then I want to use the id in the 'relatedPlaylists' data item to retrieve all the users videos.

Currently I don't think the API is returning the correct data. Any help greatly appreciated.

```js
function get_playlist() { 
    get_file('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=petermillard1&key='+YouTubeAPIkey,
    function(data) 
     { 
      show_channel(JSON.parse(data));
      get_videos();
    });
   }

   function show_channel(data) {     
    console.log('Channel data:' + data);       
    console.log('Uploads: ' + data.items.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads);
    videos=data.items.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
    console.log('Videos: ' + videos);   
   }   

  function get_videos() {
    get_file('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&id='+ videos + '&key='+YouTubeAPIkey, 
     function(data) 
      {
       create_playlist(JSON.parse(data));
      });
   }
```

Here's what shows up in the console:

```
Channel data:[object Object]

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'relatedPlaylists' of undefined
at show_channel (vget.html:170)
at vget.html:163
at XMLHttpRequest.XHR.onreadystatechange (vget.html:190)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first if the response of the `channels.list` has data.

The error you're facing is because probably no data has been returned.

For avoid retrieve the upload playlist, you can do this:

- Once your have the `channel_id`, **replace the highlighted letter** as is shown bellow:

> Channel: Microsoft Hololens:
>
> Channel_id: U**C**T2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g
>
> Uploads (playlist): U**U**T2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g

Then you can call the `get_videos()` function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I've tried this        get_file('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&forUsername=petermillard1&key='+YouTubeAPIkey,function(data) {     ... it is returning data but I don't think it's returning it in the correct format.  When I try the data api here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252C+contentDetails&forUsername=petermillard1&_h=4& it returns a data structure ... I don;t think my call returns that structure!!!

Comment: @user1106252 sorry for the late reply. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55304092/edit) with the structure you're getting and the response from the API.

Comment: Hi, no need to apologise. I couldn't figure out what the problem was so I went down a different route and my 'new' solution is partially working so I'll persevere with that. Btw, the data being returned seemd to be 'flat' data i.e. not in a structure at all. Thanks anyway.